# Can't load a Non-Laravel Composer package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-5

It's the first time that I try to load a Composer package that doesn't use a Laravel service provider or a facade.

I am trying to install this package:
https://github.com/mollie/mollie-api-php

I have followed the steps to install the package with Composer.

At the top of my controller I added:

```
require_once base_path('vendor/Mollie/API/Client.php');
```

I get the following error:

> main(): Failed opening required '../vendor/Mollie/API/Client.php' 
>       (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/lib/php')

It can't find the file. Even though the path in the error is the path where the class is located. Are there more steps I should do?

**Structure of the package:**

[image]

`composer.json` from the package:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
```

**Update:**
My controller has this namespace

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

So when i just try to new up my class it obviously can't find that class inside that namespace. So how do i ignore the namespace for 1 class

Because this will not work inside this controller:

```
$mollie = new Mollie_API_Client;
```

Comment: you do not need to require the package, composer loads it for you. Just use it

Comment: Usually I would use `use` with the namespace to the class I want, this package doesn't seem to have its classes namespaced though?

Comment: Please note in the readme: *Requiring the included autoloader. If you're using Composer, you can skip this step.* so just new it up to use it

Comment: i will edit my question, but my controller has a namespace, so it tries to load that class from the namespace, how do i ignore it for 1 class?

Comment: @Christophvh With a `use Whatever;` statement at the top of the file, or prefix the class name with a \ to start at the root (i.e. `\Whatever::hello()`).

Comment: @ceejayoz after hours of trying it was just adding '\' before my class. Wow. Thanks! You can post that as an answer and i will accept it.

Comment: @Christophvh Glad that helped. Namespaces are very powerful but definitely a bit confusing on first use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in the comments, Composer handles the autoloading for you - manually re-requiring it isn't necessary and may in fact cause problems.

> my controller has a namespace, so it tries to load that class from the namespace, how do i ignore it for 1 class?

You can reference the class with a leading \, i.e. `new \Mollie_API_Client`, which will tell PHP to look in the root instead of your controller's namespace.

You can also put `use Mollie_API_Client;` at the top of the file to accomplish a similar thing. You'll see `use` statements at the top of a lot of Laravel files for this reason.