# Add Yasumi PHP Library to Laravel (in Laravel way)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I would like to use `https://github.com/azuyalabs/yasumi` package in a laravel application.

I did the installation using:

`$ composer require azuyalabs/yasumi`

now, with a laravel package I would, after installing register the service `providers` and the `aliases` (facades) in `config/app.php`:

This library has some facades of it's own.

What would be the way to integrate this library into Laravel ?

Should I create a new Service Provider class and register `Yasumi` within that ?
Something like:

```
class YasumiServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   /**
    * Bootstrap the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function boot()
   {
       //
   }

   /**
    * Register the application services.
    *
    * @return void
    */
   public function register()
   {

   }
}
```

I wouldn't do that in the vendor folder as that is to be overwritten or even replaced at times.

Comment: Fork it, make changes, and use composer to load your fork instead of original.

Comment: I was also thinking about that, but then I should keep track all the time of the changes made on the original package. It will not be updated automatically.

Comment: Or try your luck and make a PR...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding from my comment:

Fork the repository and make changes (note, you can always make "self pull-requests" from original to your fork).

After changes are done use this inside your `composer.json` file

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "...",
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "vcs",
      "url": "https://github.com/{YOUR GITHUB NAME}/yasumi"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "azuyalabs/yasumi": "dev-{NAME OF BRANCH IN FORK}"
  },
  ...
```

> **Note**: placeholders are in use `{YOUR GITHUB NAME}` and `{NAME OF BRANCH IN FORK}`
>   **Note**: to sync your fork using webhooks see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23793062/can-forks-be-synced-automatically-in-github).

---

Additional make a PR so other can use Laravel service provider.

Comment: Browsing further I got to this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745626/cant-load-a-non-laravel-composer-package?rq=1  which made me wonder if it's really that important to load it as service providers or just use it as suggested.

Comment: https://github.com/azuyalabs/yasumi#usage  I can use it like so. 

Is there any reason for register a new Service Provider for it instead of just using it ?

Comment: You mentioned Laravel way, my answer provides kind of on how to do it, create ServiceProvider in your fork and use your fork from now on. I suggest you make a PR! And when it is merged delete your fork and use original the Laravel Way :), I am not sure I would stick with Provider but thats just personal preference you know.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler way.

In `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->singleton('yasumi', \Yasumi\Yasumi::create('USA', 2016));
}
```

then in your app, you can use

```
 $holidays = app('yasumi'); // now the equivalent of = \Yasumi\Yasumi::create('USA', 2016)
```

Then carry on as in [the documentation](https://github.com/azuyalabs/yasumi#usage).

You could even avoid the variable assignment, e.g.

```
foreach(app('yasumi')->getHolidayNames() as $name) 
{
    echo $name . PHP_EOL;
}
```