# Implementation of Yasumi in Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel, api

There is a posting from 2016 that describes how to implement Yasumi:
https://www.yasumi.dev/
into Laravel. But this looks like it completely outdated now. What is the correct way to implement it into Laravel 9?

Post I am referencing from 2016:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41266340/8207054

I am using this code (AppServiceProvider):

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Carbon\Carbon;


class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('yasumi', \Yasumi\Yasumi::create('USA', Carbon::now()->format('Y')));

    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //

    }
}
```

but it causes this error: `Illuminate\Container\Container::bind(): Argument #2 ($concrete) must be of type Closure|string|null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send function as the second parameter to singleton method like this:

```
$this->app->singleton('yasumi', function () {
    return \Yasumi\Yasumi::create('USA', Carbon::now()->format('Y'));
});
```